# Show Left Side Navigation bar in Web part pages programatically in sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I have created a Team Site named "XXXX", under this site i have created a webpart pages named "YYYYY" programmatically. When i created the web part page programmatically, it shows a left side navigation bar which is same as in the parent site "XXXX". Is there any way to show the left side navigation bar in web part page i have created programmatically?  If yes, please respond me as soon as possible.

Comment: I didn't understand - what do you get now, and what do you want to get?

Comment: I need to show the left side navigation for web part pages programmatically..... in sharpeoint 2010

Comment: And what do you get now?